# What's wrong with my Python about 'TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'float''

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I don't know why the code can't go well. Here is my code:

```
from ipywidgets import interact_manual
def BMI(height, weight):
    height = (float(height) / 100)**2
    weight = float(weight)
    BMI = weight/height
    print('Your BMI is {:.2f}'.format(BMI))

interact_manual(BMI, height='Please enter your height', weight='Please enter your weight')

if BMI<18.5:
    print('Eat more!')
elif BMI != 24:
    print('Take care of your health, eat less')
else:
    print('Nice:)')
```

Comment: try not to compare the function itself with a value but the result, so the condition should look more like `BMI(heightGoesHere, weightGoesThere) < limit`. Also it is a bad idea to use the same identifier for variable names and function names at the same time ... please avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be comparing the function with a value.
Try taking the inputs for height and weight from the user and passing them to the function `BMI()`.

```
def BMI(height, weight):
   height = (float(height) / 100)**2
   weight = float(weight)
   BMI = weight/height
   print('Your BMI is {:.2f}'.format(BMI))
   return BMI

height,weight = list(map(float,input().split()))

if BMI(height,weight)<18.5:
    print('Eat more!')
elif BMI(height,weight) != 24:
    print('Take care of your health, eat less')
else:
    print('Nice:)')
```